# Dinosaurs vs. humans

Tags: evolution

If dinosaurs were here so much longer than humans, why did their natural selection not account for higher intelligence, as is the case in humans?

Comment: Perhaps this is already answered here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11254/why-were-dinosaurs-not-as-smart-as-we-are?rq=1

Comment: Some dinosaurs are extremely intelligent, being able to [use tools](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/crows-are-really-good-at-making-tools-scientists-have-discovered) and [make tools](https://onekindplanet.org/animal-behaviour/tool-use/tool-use-in-new-caledonian-crows/). However, this is a duplicate question, VTC

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Biology.SE. Even if the question is short, it is sufficient to show a good number of common misconception about evolutionary processes. I'll be brief in commenting on them and will invite you to seek for more knowledge in an intro course and related posts.

## Phrasing

> their natural selection

Natural selection is a concept (the concept of fitness variance in the population correlated with an additive genetic variance). Natural selection is not a thing that is owned be a population. It is not "theirs"

## Your misunderstandings

**Evolutionary time**

Any living species on earth has 3.5 billion years of evolutionary time. There is no exception to that as we all share a common ancestor. Humans are not less evolved than a crocodile or a bacteria. We all have the exact same evolutionary time.

**Evolution of intelligence**

Higher intelligence is NOT what natural selection will tend to. Having high intelligence is most often rather negatively correlated with fitness.

Related posts:

- [Why evolution should not be equated with progress?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57356/why-evolution-should-not-be-equated-with-progress)
- [Why were dinosaurs not as smart as we are?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11254/why-were-dinosaurs-not-as-smart-as-we-are)

**Source of information**

You would make good use of a very short and very introductory course to evolutionary biology. There is a large number of free ressources online. You might want for example to consider [Understanding Evolution by UC Berkeley](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01).